# Button is displayed disabled even it is enable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have added button in asp.net code. but it is displayed as disabled.

Here is my code.

```
                TableCell cell15 = new TableCell();    
                cell15.Width = 100;  
                cell15.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;  
                Button Apply = new Button();  
                Apply.ID = "Apply_Button";  
                Apply.Text = "Apply";  
                Apply.Width = 50;  
                Apply.Height = 20;  
                Apply.Visible = true;  
                Apply.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Inherit;  
                Apply.UseSubmitBehavior = true;  
                Apply.CausesValidation = true;  
                Apply.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Inherit;  
                Apply.EnableTheming = true;  
                Apply.CausesValidation = true;  
                Apply.Enabled = true;  
                Apply.OnClientClick = Apply_Click(sender, e);  
                cell15.Controls.Add(Apply);  
                row8.Cells.Add(cell15);
```

Generated HTMl is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Apply_Button" value="Apply"
 disabled="disabled" id="MainContent_Apply_Button" style="height:20px;width:50px;">
```

Comment: what html is generated for it? Please get it using `inspect element` and paste here.

Comment: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Apply_Button" value="Apply" disabled="disabled" id="MainContent_Apply_Button" style="height:20px;width:50px;">

Comment: Do you have any `javascript` for `enable` or `disable` button?

Comment: no, i haven't add any javascript

Comment: Change `Apply.OnClientClick = Apply_Click(sender, e);` to `Apply.Click += Apply_Click;` and try again. Because `OnClientClick` must be `javascript` codes.

Comment: giving me an error.Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0161: 'UpComing.Apply_Click()': not all code paths return a value

Source Error:


Line 320:    }
Line 321:
Line 322:    private EventHandler Apply_Click()

Comment: Because you call Apply_Click method. You not set event handler. Event return type is void.

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Write `Apply.Click += Apply_Click;` not `Apply.Click += Apply_Click(sender,e);`

Comment: worked, but still button is disabled. :(

Comment: I tested your code and button is enabled. Image -> [link](http://s29.postimg.org/92s6o3w8n/image.png)

Comment: but men i am not able to click on button!!!! without it how click event gonna  load???

Answer (score 1):

```
Do you have any update panel, try to place button inside update panel
```

OR (use javascript) :

```
document.getElementById("YourButtonID").setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

Code Behind :

```
YourButtonID.disabled = false;
```

Comment: no, i haven't add button on .aspx file. but i want buttons as per query result so i added it in code file.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code.

```
public partial class UpComing : System.Web.UI.Page


        String sel = "SELECT Cmpny_Data.C_Name, Cmpny_Data.J_location, Cmpny_Data.Copm_desc, Cmpny_Data.J_Crtra, Cmpny_Data.Cmps_Date, Cmpny_Data.Last_date, Cmpny_Data.Elg_cTRTA FROM Cmpny_Data INNER JOIN Details ON Cmpny_Data.Elg_cTRTA < Details.cpi WHERE (Details.En_no='" + Session["uname"].ToString() + "') AND (Cmpny_Data.Last_date > SYSDATETIME()) ";
        cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sel, obj.con);
        dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            C_N.Text += dr[0].ToString() + '`';
            C_P.Text += dr[2].ToString() + '`';
            J_C.Text += dr[3].ToString() + '`';
            J_L.Text += dr[1].ToString() + '`';
            E_C.Text += dr[6].ToString() + '`';
            C_D.Text += dr[4].ToString() + '`';
            L_D.Text += dr[5].ToString() + '`';
        }
        dr.Dispose();
        cmd2.Dispose();
        obj.con.Close();
        String AllCN = C_N.Text;
        String AllCP = C_P.Text;
        String AllJC = J_C.Text;
        String AllJL = J_L.Text;
        String AllEC = E_C.Text;
        String AllCD = C_D.Text;
        String AllLD = L_D.Text;

        char separator = '`';

        String[] CNs = AllCN.Split(separator);
        String[] CPs = AllCP.Split(separator);
        String[] JCs = AllJC.Split(separator);
        String[] JLs = AllJL.Split(separator);
        String[] ECs = AllEC.Split(separator);
        String[] CDs = AllCD.Split(separator);
        String[] LDs = AllLD.Split(separator);

        C_N.Text = null;
        C_P.Text = null;
        J_C.Text = null;
        J_L.Text = null;
        E_C.Text = null;
        C_D.Text = null;
        L_D.Text = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < ttlq; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Width = 100;
                cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.ID = "Lable1";
                label1.Text = " Company Name :  ";
                cell1.Controls.Add(label1);
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);

                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Width = 650;
                cell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label C_Name = new Label();

                C_Name.Width = 650;
                C_Name.Height = 20;
                C_Name.ID = "Cmp_Name";
                C_Name.Text = CNs[i];
                cell2.Controls.Add(C_Name);
                row.Cells.Add(cell2);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row);

            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                cell3.Width = 100;
                cell3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label2 = new Label();
                label2.ID = "Lable2";
                label2.Text = " Company Profile :  ";
                cell3.Controls.Add(label2);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell3);

                TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                cell4.Width = 650;
                cell4.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label C_Prof = new Label();
                C_Prof.Width = 650;
                C_Prof.Height = 10;
                C_Prof.ID = "Cmp_Prf";
                C_Prof.Text = CPs[i];
                cell4.Controls.Add(C_Prof);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell4);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row1);

            TableRow row2 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
                cell5.Width = 100;
                cell5.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label3 = new Label();
                label3.ID = "Lable3";
                label3.Text = " Company Profile :  ";
                cell5.Controls.Add(label3);
                row2.Cells.Add(cell5);

                TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();
                cell6.Width = 650;
                cell6.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label J_Crit = new Label();
                J_Crit.Width = 650;
                J_Crit.Height = 10;
                J_Crit.ID = "Job_Crit";
                J_Crit.Text = JCs[i];
                cell6.Controls.Add(J_Crit);
                row2.Cells.Add(cell6);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row2);

            TableRow row3 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell7 = new TableCell();
                cell7.Width = 100;
                cell7.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label4 = new Label();
                label4.ID = "Lable4";
                label4.Text = " Job Location :  ";
                cell7.Controls.Add(label4);
                row3.Cells.Add(cell7);

                TableCell cell8 = new TableCell();
                cell8.Width = 650;
                cell8.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label J_Loc = new Label();
                J_Loc.Width = 650;
                J_Loc.Height = 10;
                J_Loc.ID = "Job_Location";
                J_Loc.Text = JLs[i];
                cell8.Controls.Add(J_Loc);
                row3.Cells.Add(cell8);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row3);

            TableRow row4 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell9 = new TableCell();
                cell9.Width = 100;
                cell9.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label5 = new Label();
                label5.ID = "Lable5";
                label5.Text = " Eligibility Criteria :  ";
                cell9.Controls.Add(label5);
                row4.Cells.Add(cell9);

                TableCell cell10 = new TableCell();
                cell10.Width = 650;
                cell10.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label E_Crit = new Label();
                E_Crit.Width = 650;
                E_Crit.Height = 10;
                E_Crit.ID = "Elg_Crit";
                E_Crit.Text = ECs[i];
                cell10.Controls.Add(E_Crit);
                row4.Cells.Add(cell10);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row4);

            TableRow row5 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell11 = new TableCell();
                cell11.Width = 100;
                cell11.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label6 = new Label();
                label6.ID = "Lable6";
                label6.Text = " Campus Date :  ";
                cell11.Controls.Add(label6);
                row5.Cells.Add(cell11);

                TableCell cell12 = new TableCell();
                cell12.Width = 650;
                cell12.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label C_Date = new Label();
                C_Date.Width = 650;
                C_Date.ID = "Camp_Date";
                C_Date.Text = CDs[i];
                cell12.Controls.Add(C_Date);
                row5.Cells.Add(cell12);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row5);

            TableRow row7 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell13 = new TableCell();
                cell13.Width = 100;
                cell13.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label label7 = new Label();
                label7.ID = "Lable7";
                label7.Text = " Last Date :  ";
                cell13.Controls.Add(label7);
                row7.Cells.Add(cell13);

                TableCell cell14 = new TableCell();
                cell14.Width = 650;
                cell14.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label L_Date = new Label();
                L_Date.Width = 650;
                L_Date.ID = "Last_Date";
                L_Date.Text = LDs[i];
                cell14.Controls.Add(L_Date);
                row7.Cells.Add(cell14);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row7);

            TableRow row8 = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                TableCell cell15 = new TableCell();
                cell15.Width = 100;
                cell15.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Button Apply = new Button();
                Apply.ID = "Apply_Button";
                Apply.Text = "Apply";
                Apply.Width = 50;
                Apply.Height = 20;
                Apply.Visible = true;
                Apply.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Inherit;
                Apply.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                Apply.CausesValidation = true;
                Apply.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Inherit;
                Apply.EnableTheming = true;
                Apply.CausesValidation = true;
                Apply.Enabled = true;
                Apply.Click += Apply_Click;
                cell15.Controls.Add(Apply);
                row8.Cells.Add(cell15);

                TableCell cell16 = new TableCell(); ;
                cell16.Width = 100;
                cell16.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                Label Alert = new Label();
                //Alert.Text = dr1.ToString();
                Alert.Text = "You have applied for this campus. If you are not interested for this campus, please contact T&P Cell.";
                Alert.Font.Bold = true;
                cell16.Controls.Add(Alert);
                row8.Cells.Add(cell16);


                openConn conn = new openConn();
                conn.checkdb();
                String sel3 = "Select * from  Student_Company where [Enrollment]='" + Session["uname"].ToString() + "' and ([Cmpny_Name]='" + CNs[i] + "')";
                cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sel3, conn.con);
                dr1 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr1.HasRows)
                {
                    Alert.Visible = true;
                    Apply.Visible = false;
                    dr1.Dispose();
                    cmd3.Dispose();
                    conn.con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Alert.Visible = false;
                    Apply.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(row8);

            //table1.BorderWidth = 1;

        }
    }

}

protected void Apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openConn obj = new openConn();
    obj.checkdb();
    cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Student_Company Values('" + Session["uname"].ToString() + "', '" + C_Name.Text + "')", obj.con);
    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd4.Dispose();
    obj.con.Close();
}
```

}